# SQL: Select another column from a column that has the same value

Tags: sql, select

I would like to select ORDER_NUMBER from that same group of ID.
Which the pairing conditions are as follows:

- A pairs with B (A is the main tag order. B is the minor tag order) and B pairs with C
- X pairs with Y (X is the main tag order. Y is the minor tag order) and Y pairs with Z

  ```
    ID   ORDER    ORDER_NUMBER        Tag
    ---+--------+-----------------+---------
    47   48      200000002814           A
    47   49      30000000266600001      B
    47   49      30000000266600000      C
    50   51      200000001999           A
    50   52      30000000266600002      B
    50   52      30000000266605763      C
    ..   ...     ...                    ..
    ..   ...     ...                    ..
    250  251     200000001932           X
    250  252     30000000266600121      Y
    250  252     30000000266605452      Z
  ```

**Expected result:**

```
   Tag_main| Tag_minor| ORDER_NUMBER_main  | ORDER_NUMBER_minor
-------------+--------------+--------------
    A      |    B     | 200000002814       |  30000000266600001
    B      |    C     | 30000000266600001  |  30000000266600000      
    A      |    B     | 200000001999       |  30000000266600002
    B      |    C     | 30000000266600002  |  30000000266605763  
    X      |    Y     | 200000001932       |  30000000266600121
    Y      |    Z     | 30000000266600121  |  30000000266605452
```

How can I write the code?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` along with a self join we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Tag) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT
    t1.Tag AS Tag_main,
    t2.Tag AS Tag_minor,
    t1.ORDER_NUMBER AS ORDER_NUMBER_main,
    t2.ORDER_NUMBER AS ORDER_NUMBER_minor
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
ORDER BY
    t1.ID,
    t1.Tag;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: I have edited that It has many groups of Tag, is it can use WHERE with Tag?

Comment: @Karina Just remove the restriction in the `WHERE` clause of the outer query and it should still work.

Comment: Can I use CASE WHEN if I do not join the table?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  My approach hinges on a self join to bring the parent and child aligned in a single record in the output.

Comment: I mean it like.. Can I write SELECT (CASE WHEN t.RN = 1 THEN t.ORDER_NUMBER WHEN t.RN = 2 THEN t.ORDER_NUMBER END) AS ORDER_NUMBER_main , but I dont know how to query for ORDER_NUMBER_minor with using CASE WHEN

Answer (score 0):

check this -

```
create table alpha
(
    ID int,
    [Order] int,
    Order_Number int,
    Tag char
)


insert into alpha
select 1, 123, 7997, 'A' union
select 1, 35, 46, 'B' union
select 1, 46, 464, 'C' union
select 2, 35, 68, 'A' union
select 2, 35, 424, 'B' union
select 2, 35, 799, 'C' union
select 3, 68, 2424, 'A' union
select 3, 5, 7979, 'B' union
select 3, 770, 33, 'C' 



select a.Tag 'tag_major', b.Tag 'tag_minor', a.Order_Number 'order_main', b.Order_Number 'order_minor' from 
alpha a join alpha b
on a.ID = b.ID and a.Tag = CHAR(ASCII(b.Tag) - 1)
order by a.ID
```

[image]